# Tail function for "safe list" using GADTs

Tags: haskell, gadt

I was reading through [a GADT walkthrough](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT) and got stuck on one of the exercises. The given data structure is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, EmptyDataDecls, KindSignatures #-}
data NotSafe
data Safe
data MarkedList :: * -> * -> * where
    Nil  :: MarkedList t NotSafe
    Cons :: a -> MarkedList a b -> MarkedList a c
```

The exercise is to implement a `safeTail` function. I'd like it to act similar to the `tail` function in Prelude:

```
safeTail (Cons 'c' (Cons 'a' (Cons 't' Nil))) == Cons 'a' (Cons 't' Nil)
safeTail (Cons 'x' Nil)                       == Nil
safeTail Nil  -- type error (not runtime!)
```

<sup>(I didn't actually define `==`, but hopefully it's clear what I mean)</sup>

Can this be done? I'm not entirely sure what the type would even be... maybe `safeTail :: MarkedList a Safe -> MarkedList a NotSafe`?

Comment: Note that the solution that was linked from the chapter until five minutes ago was obviously wrong. Thank you for indirectly leading me to that "bug".

Comment: I think you've accepted the wrong answer here even if the one you accepted is also interesting. The exercise doesn't invite you to change the data type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to implement `safeTail` if you change the type structure a bit:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, EmptyDataDecls, KindSignatures #-}

data Safe a
data NotSafe

data MarkedList :: * -> * -> * where
    Nil  :: MarkedList t NotSafe
    Cons :: a -> MarkedList a b -> MarkedList a (Safe b)

safeHead :: MarkedList a (Safe b) -> a
safeHead (Cons h _) = h

safeTail :: MarkedList a (Safe b) -> MarkedList a b
safeTail (Cons _ t) = t
```

The problem with the original `safeTail :: MarkedList a Safe -> MarkedList a b` is that `b` can be any type - not necessarily the same type that the tail of the list is marked with. This is fixed here by reflecting the list structure on the type level which allows the return type of `safeTail` to be appropriately constrained.

Comment: note: this is exactly the same as encoding the length in the type, since the index here is exactly the type of natural numbers.

Comment: Of course, when you do this, you might consider renaming `NotSafe` and `Safe` to `Zero` and `Succ`. :-) The list's type tells you what its length is, not just whether its length is 0 or not.

Comment: Very neat! I like that `safeTail $ safeTail $ Cons 'c' $ Cons 'a' $ Cons 't' Nil` works here, too. My proposed type signature in the question wouldn't have allowed for that.

Comment: I think this is an interesting answer but wrong because the exercise doesn't invite you to change the data type.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it can be done. The trick is to turn that existentially-quantified contained list into a list of a known type: specifically, a `NotSafe` one!

```
unsafe :: MarkedList a b -> MarkedList a NotSafe
unsafe Nil = Nil
unsafe (Cons a b) = Cons a b
```

Now we can take the tail safely:

```
safeTail :: MarkedList a Safe -> MarkedList a NotSafe
safeTail (Cons a b) = unsafe b
```

Additionally, this pattern match is complete. You won't get a warning from `-fwarn-incomplete-patterns`, and if you try to add a `Nil` clause you'll get an error. Let's turn on `StandaloneDeriving`, derive a `Show` instance, and test out your samples:

```
*Main> safeTail (Cons 'c' (Cons 'a' (Cons 't' Nil)))
Cons 'a' (Cons 't' Nil)
*Main> safeTail (Cons 'x' Nil)
Nil
*Main> safeTail Nil

<interactive>:10:10:
    Couldn't match type `NotSafe' with `Safe'
    Expected type: MarkedList a0 Safe
      Actual type: MarkedList a0 NotSafe
    In the first argument of `safeTail', namely `Nil'
    In the expression: safeTail Nil
    In an equation for `it': it = safeTail Nil
```

Comment: Your function doesn't allow to take `safeTail $ safeTail` on any list which makes it kind of useless. Still, you answer the question and the accepted answer doesn't because the exercise asks to implement safeTail but doesn't invite you to change the data type. Actually I think it's kind of a crappy exercise for that reason.